# Issues while installing packages in angular

Tags: angular, npm, web-development-server

I am having issues while doing "ng add @angular/localize" or "ng add @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap".
I am a beginner and don't understand what the error indicates. I am attaching the screenshots.

[angular version screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4DkOq.png)
 [error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ipuas.png)

`
PS D:\CompleteJavaClasses\angularclasscjc\angular-project> ng add @angular/localize
ℹ Using package manager: npm
✔ Found compatible package version: @angular/localize@14.0.1.
✔ Package information loaded.

The package @angular/localize@14.0.1 will be installed and executed.
Would you like to proceed? Yes
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE could not resolve
npm ERR!
npm ERR! While resolving: @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap@12.1.2
npm ERR! Found: @angular/common@14.0.1
npm ERR! node_modules/@angular/common
npm ERR!   peer @angular/common@"14.0.1" from @angular/forms@14.0.1
npm ERR!   node_modules/@angular/forms
npm ERR!     @angular/forms@"^14.0.0" from the root project
npm ERR!   peer @angular/common@"14.0.1" from @angular/platform-browser@14.0.1
npm ERR!   node_modules/@angular/platform-browser
npm ERR!     peer @angular/platform-browser@"14.0.1" from @angular/forms@14.0.1
npm ERR!     node_modules/@angular/forms
npm ERR!       @angular/forms@"^14.0.0" from the root project
npm ERR!     peer @angular/platform-browser@"14.0.1" from @angular/platform-browser-dynamic@14.0.1
npm ERR!     node_modules/@angular/platform-browser-dynamic
npm ERR!       @angular/platform-browser-dynamic@"^14.0.0" from the root project
npm ERR!     2 more (@angular/router, the root project)
npm ERR!   3 more (@angular/platform-browser-dynamic, @angular/router, the root project)
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer @angular/common@"^13.0.0" from @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap@12.1.2
npm ERR! node_modules/@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap
npm ERR!   @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap@"^12.1.2" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Conflicting peer dependency: @angular/common@13.3.11
npm ERR! node_modules/@angular/common
npm ERR!   peer @angular/common@"^13.0.0" from @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap@12.1.2
npm ERR!   node_modules/@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap
npm ERR!     @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap@"^12.1.2" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR!
npm ERR! See C:\Users\91976\AppData\Local\npm-cache\eresolve-report.txt for a full report.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\91976\AppData\Local\npm-cache_logs\2022-06-12T13_32_55_358Z-debug-0.log
✖ Packages installation failed, see above.
`

Answer (score -1):

what do you see when you run this command in you project:

```
ng add @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap
```

and share it with us.